# Указатели на функции

Tags: c, указатели

Объясните, пожалуйста, есть ли разница между двумя записями, если есть, то какая?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int sum(int a, int b){
    return a+b;
}

main(){

    int (*fun)(int , int) = NULL;
    fun = sum;

    printf("%d\n\n", fun(12,14));
    printf("%d\n\n",(*fun)(12,14));


   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Разница существует лишь на абстрактном концептуальном уровне. Фактической разницы нет.

Получение адреса функции тоже можно записать как `fun = sum;` или как `fun = &sum;`. Разницы тоже нет.

Можно, разве что, посоветовать быть единообразным, т.е. либо использовать явные операторы и там, и там

```
fun = &sum;
(*fun)(12,14);
```

либо не использовать их ни там, ни там

```
fun = sum;
fun(12,14);
```

Хотя и этот совет, возможно, не заслуживает большого внимания.

Answer (score 4):

Разницы по сути нет никакой, но этот вопрос заслуживает отдельного внимания из-за своей истории.

В первом случае `(*fun)()`, так как `fun` указывает на ф-цию `sum`, то `*fun` - это ни что иное как `sum`. Во втором случае, когда `fun ()` - это можно объяснить тем, что функция и указатель на нее - взаимозаменяемы!

Но вот почему так? Почему не использовать один из подходов? Дело в том, что язык Си бурно развивался еще до того, как был опубликован первый стандарт и к этому времени уже были использованы оба варианта разными командами разработчиков. В частности первый подход выбрали разработчики, которые расширяли `Unix` в Bell Labs, а второй - которые расширяли `Unix`в Беркли. Стандарт, в целях совместимости, разрешил использовать оба подхода как эквивалентные.

Comment: О каком "первом подходе" и "втором подходе" идет речь? В чем суть различия?

Comment: Читай: "во-первых - во-вторых" - исправлю на более понятное

Comment: Исправил - надеюсь так понятно

Comment: Нет, не понятно. Мой вопрос о *сути* различия - это вопрос: речь идет о косметической манере писать код или о каких-то внутреннних различиях в компиляторах? "Уже были использованы оба решения" - в чем суть "решений"? О чем говорилось в "решениях"?

Comment: Не могу понять что ты хочешь выяснить... Еще раз: разницы нет - компилятор обрабатывает эти строки одинаково. Я написал почему используются оба варианта (возможно слово "решение" вводит в заблуждение) - вот и все.

Comment: Я хочу выяснить, почему в истории языка С при вызове функции произошел переход от `функция()` (как было в C Reference Manual), к `указатель()` (как стало в стандарте С89/90). Вы упоминаете какую-то зацепку про Berkley и Bell Labs. Я хочу знать детали и подробности. Где про это можно почитать?

Comment: Поподробнее - не знаю, загуглите. Но вот лично я это вычитал из книги Прата по Си. В 6-ом издании это страница 614